# Convert CSV Boolean-enumerations to bitfield in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bit-manipulation

In bash (>=3) Given a line from a csv file such as:

```
arbitrary descriptor, uid, PASS, FAIL, NA, PASS, PASS, CLEAR
```

I want to compute `00100110`b as a result. The pattern here being that the PASS columns become 1's in a bit field. The result above is equivalent to 0x26 or 38 decimal.

My attempt was initially to echo into awk, however, not sure how to test <$whatever_number>. Assuming this approach I suppose a pattern match result would output to a ternary print statement for 1 or 0. Then maybe xxd to go from ASCII to binary.

something like(?):

```
echo "arbitrary descriptor, uid, PASS, FAIL, NA, PASS, PASS, CLEAR" | awk -F',' '{??? ~ /\s*PASS\s*/ ? print "1" : print "0"}' |  xxd -b
```

A second approach using sed also didn't quite get there:

```
echo "arbitrary descriptor, uid, PASS, FAIL, NA, PASS, PASS, CLEAR" | sed 's/,\s*PASS\s*/1/g'| sed 's/[^1]*?,/0/g  |  xxd -b
```

ideas?

Comment: so you want to (re)map each field to a `0` or `1` where .... `PASS` becomes a `1` ... and everything else becomes a `0`?

Comment: can a field contain a string like `arbitrary PASS descriptor`, `MYPASS` or `PASSWORD`? if the answer is 'yes' then how should these fields be (re)mapped? `1` since they *contain* the string `PASS`, or a `0` since they are not *equal* to the string `PASS`?

Comment: As usual with CSV: can you have commas inside fields, can fields be quoted, do you really have spaces after each comma, always or just sometimes,...?

Comment: will all fields *always* be separated by a comma and a space (`, `) as is shown in the one-line sample?

Comment: Typically " PASS ". Although there is no preclusion to rule out "PASS", "     PASS",  "PASS   ", etc. The fields will ALWAYS be separated by a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F' *, *' -v OFS= '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=($i=="PASS")} 1' file
00100110
```

Comment: I had a little trouble getting back to binary. Used what you just taught me to synth the bit field in awk... Thx:         echo $failed_line | awk -F' *, *' -v OFS= '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++){sum+=($i=="PASS")*2**(i-1)}} END{print "bitfield="sum+0}'

Comment: looks like this solution won't work if there is whitespace after the last field, and that field is PASS, eg:  "arbitrary descriptor, uid, PASS, FAIL, NA, PASS, PASS, PASS          ". btw... what is the 1 (before "' file" at the end for?) thx

Comment: echo "arbitrary descriptor, uid, PASS, FAIL, NA, PASS, PASS, PASS          " | awk -F',' -v OFS= '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i=($i ~ "PASS")} 1'
00100111
...seems to work.

Comment: Don't do that or it'll fail with a false match on SURPASSED, etc.. If you can have blanks at start or end of the line then state that in your question and include it in your sample input/output but there's various ways to handle it including putting `{gsub(/^ +| +$/,"")}` at the start of the script to remove those blanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN { RS = ", "; ORS = "" } # treat a field as a record

$1 == "PASS" { print 1 }
$1 != "PASS" { print 0 }

END { print "\n" }

$ awk -f filter.awk data.txt
```

Setting a special built-in Awk variable `RS` (Record Separator) to `", "` makes Awk treat each field as a separate record.

So, instead of seeing the data as 1 record of 8 fields:

`arbitrary descriptor` `uid` `PASS` `FAIL` `NA` `PASS` `PASS` `CLEAR`

Awk sees the data as 8 records of 1 field each:

`arbitrary descriptor`

`uid`

`PASS`

`FAIL`

`NA`

`PASS`

`PASS`

`CLEAR`

This approach takes advantage of Awk's automatic main loop processing (instead of iteration over the fields of a record

```
for ( i = 1; i <= NF; i++ )...
```

manually).

And results in a shorter, cleaner and arguably more efficient code.

Comment: You should mention that requires a non-POSIX extension to support multi-char RS and so it'll only work in some awks, e.g. GNU awk.

Comment: @Ed Morton  Thank you for your comment. I tested it with BSD Awk 20210215 & Mawk 1.3.4 20190203 and it works as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'arbitrary descriptor, uid, PASS, FAIL, NA, PASS, PASS, CLEAR' |
```

---

```
mawk 'gsub("PASS.", !_, $!++NF) gsub("[^01]+", _)' FS=', *' OFS='0,'
```

---

```
00100110
```